# Need help for Fire Detection System design

Tags: design, sensors, safety, battery

As a Building Services Engineering student, my current project involves the design of fire detection system of a newly-installed at-home EV charging system. The EV chargers are installed in the carpark, and heat detector would be used. The heat detectors are connected to a new fire control panel, which is connected to an existing fire control panel.

As I have never learnt the specific design of fire detection systems, and none of my supervisors specialize in this field, I find myself rather directionless. On what design criteria should I use to select the appropriate heat detector? Do I have to calculate the emergency batteries for heat detectors, or do only fire alarms and the fire control panel need it?

Comment: Just heat does not indicate fire.  Burning wood does.  Think of what your EV fire would look like and how it differs from the typical hot car (or cold car with simeone trying to warm it with a heater)

Comment: Check out the temperature sensors used for fire detection, especially check out "rate of rise".

Comment: I would suggest using chemical sensors, i.e., CO or HC rather than a heat (temperature) sensor to get a more useful measure of the initial stages of a fire.  With heat sensor something is already pretty well combusting before an alarm is raised.

Comment: Sorry I mean fire detection system, I made a typo